# how to search a date by month in sql server c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have columns in database `GRP`(PK), `start_date`, `end_date`.`start_date`/`end_date` have data type date.

I have a datagridview, a combobox containing 12 months and a button to search records by month. How to do that, I have no idea.

Can somebody give me idea about that. I want to do the same for year.

Thanks.

Comment: have you bind your table data to `Gridview` ? How did you bind it ?

Comment: Search Sql Server docs on [Function Month](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx), try your query directly with Sql Server Management Studio and then write the code

Comment: yes, data is visible in datagridview when form is loaded

Comment: so , how did you bind it ? show me your code !

Comment: objc = new SqlConnection(c);
objcmd = new SqlCommand("select * from leaves", objc);
objda = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd.CommandText, objc);
objds = new System.Data.DataSet();
objda.Fill(objds, "leaves");
dataGridView3.DataSource = objds.Tables["leaves"].DefaultView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [datepart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) TSQL function in your query,
for example if you want to load only record which are in 2nd month:

```
SELECT *   FROM leaves WHERE DATEPART(month, start_date)=2 or DATEPART(month, end_date)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code:

```
declare @StartDate date
set @StartDate = getdate()
select @StartDate 

Select MONTH(@StartDate)

SELECT *
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE MONTH(StartDate) = @Month
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ado.net you should take a look at [Transact-SQL Month](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187813.aspx). If the Application gets more complex, I would recommend using Entity Framework.

`Select * from table where Month(StartDate) = @Month`

Comment: thanks brthr, what to write in place of @Month

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like

```
string _query = String.Format("select * from leaves where Month(start_date) ='{0}' and Month(end_date) ='{0}'",yourComboxBoxSelectedValue);

objcmd = new SqlCommand(_query, objc);
```